# How can I optimize this code to make it faster?

Tags: python, performance, optimization

I performing a set of division operations and reshaping on a HDF5 file. As my datapoints is around 4000 in number, how can I optimize this code to make it more faster?

```
def pre_proc_data():
    jointMatrix = np.array([], dtype=np.float64).reshape(0, 500 * 17)
    hdf5_file = h5py.File("/home/Data.hdf5")

    for j in range(len(hdf5_file["vector"])):
        # Normalization
        norm_vec = hdf5_file["vector"][j]
        norm_vec[:, 0] = (norm_vec[:, 0] - (-3.059)) / 6.117  # W0 - Left and right
        norm_vec[:, 5] = (norm_vec[:, 5] - (-3.059)) / 6.117
        norm_vec[:, 1] = (norm_vec[:, 1] - (-1.5707)) / 3.6647  # W1 
        norm_vec[:, 6] = (norm_vec[:, 6] - (-1.5707)) / 3.6647
        norm_vec[:, 2] = (norm_vec[:, 2] - (-3.059)) / 6.117  # W2 
        norm_vec[:, 14] = (norm_vec[:, 14] - (-3.059)) / 6.117
        norm_vec[:, 3] = (norm_vec[:, 3] - (-1.7016)) / 3.4033  # S0 
        norm_vec[:, 10] = (norm_vec[:, 10] - (-1.7016)) / 3.4033
        norm_vec[:, 4] = (norm_vec[:, 4] - (-2.147)) / 3.194  # s1 
        norm_vec[:, 8] = (norm_vec[:, 8] - (-2.147)) / 3.194

        norm_vec[:, 11] = (norm_vec[:, 11] - (-3.0541)) / 6.1083  # eo 
        norm_vec[:, 15] = (norm_vec[:, 15] - (-3.0541)) / 6.1083
        norm_vec[:, 12] = (norm_vec[:, 12] - (-0.05)) / 2.67  # e1 
        norm_vec[:, 16] = (norm_vec[:, 16] - (-0.05)) / 2.67

        reshaped_vec = hdf5_file["vector"][j].reshape(500 * 17)
        jointMatrix = np.vstack((jointMatrix, reshaped_vec))

    return jointMatrix


jointMatrix = pre_proc_data()
```

Comment: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Did you tried multiprocessing module? It has a cool parallel map function. I think this for can be parallelized.